# mapping nhibernate parent/child relationship the 'other' way round

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

using FluentNhibernate;

I am trying to persist a seemingly simple object model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Config Config { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public int ConfigId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ConfigField1 { get; set; }
    public string ConfigField2 { get; set; }
}
```

and the database looks like: (not syntactically correct)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Config](
[ConfigId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ConfigField1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ConfigField2] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Out of the box fluent-nhibernate will try and map this as a foreign key on the `Products` table, eg:

> INSERT INTO Products (Name, Config_id) VALUES (?, ?);

I don't want it to do this, rather I was hoping the mapping would insert Products first then the config second with `ProductId` being inserted into the Config table.

I've pulled my hair out trying overrides and reading links such as [this](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=88) and [this](http://jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/) but still can't get it to do what I want. I am working with *existing data and code* so I would rather not change the database table definitions or the domain object. There is a bit more going on than what this example paints so if we could avoid discussions on domain model design that would be great. I have a link to a spike of this project [here](http://wallaceturner.com/get/FluentNHibernateSubClassTest.zip) (assumes database exists)

my current fluent mappings are:

```
public class ProductOverrides : IAutoMappingOverride<Product>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Product> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("ProductId");            
        mapping.Table("Products");
    }
}

public class ConfigOverrides : IAutoMappingOverride<Config>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Config> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.ConfigId);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this? http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/

Comment: Can you explain how that helps? thats a one to one relationship which isnt what i need as `Config` has its own primary key `ConfigId` but needs to be linked back to Products via `ProductId`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to map a one-to-one relationship as a one-to-many by mapping what would be the many side twice. That won't work. NHibernate is strict in its definition of one-to-one and requires that both sides have the same primary key, so that won't work either.

I've [butted heads with this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208796/modeling-one-to-zero-or-one-relationships-z-cardinality) and the best workaround I found is to model it as a standard on-to-many but only allow one item in the collection by encapsulating access to the it. In your case I would guess that Product would be the one side and Config the many.

Comment: to confirm, that would require adding a `List<Config> Configs` property to the `Product` class?

Comment: No, add the collection (I recommend set mapping instead of list) as a private member and map it using an access strategy. Then control the collection through a public Config property that only allows one Config in the collection. See the linked question.

Comment: yea ok, its not ideal firstly as i'm trying to avoid changing my domain objects just to please nhibernate. secondly i'm sending it across the wire and a `Set` I'm assuming is an nhibernate class which i can't have.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Config is used elsewhere but you could ignore ConfigId as its identity

```
public class Config
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string ConfigField1 { get; set; }
    public string ConfigField2 { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public class ProductMap()
    {
        HasOne(p => p.Config);
    }
}

public class ConfigMap : ClassMap<Config>
{
    public class ConfigMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id, "ProductId").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Product");

        References(c => c.Product, "ProductId");
        Map(c => ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks as always for both answers. The issue with both of these solutions is that Config is also used by *another* class as a 'component' which rules out using ProductId as the key column (as its not defined on `Config` when `Config` is a property of a class other than `Product`. I'm thinking the easiest thing is to redefine the database to store `ConfigId` in the Product table

Comment: of course changing the db if possible is the easiest. but you can map Config on the other class also as component with a different joincolumn()

Comment: What would you then do about this line tho:
Id(c => c.Id, "ProductId").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Product");

that is, how will the other class add its own Id into the Config table given the aforementioned mapping is required for the `Product` Config to save?

Comment: "by another class as a 'component'" --> my comment was for the component mapping you see in my other answer.

Comment: ok understood. i will get that method working with my spike and mark it as answered when complete. irl i'm going to just update the columns as thats much easier for nhibernate; Generally speaking does nHibernate do this the 'standard' way or is it arbitrary?

Comment: NHibernate makes it easy to work with the standard way but has a lot of features aimed at non-standard database schemas

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to join and map as Component

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public class ProductMap()
    {
        Join("Config", join => 
        {
            join.KeyColumn("ProductId");
            join.Component(p => p.Config, c =>
            {
                c.Map(...);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Disadvantage is that you can not query Config directly, you have to query through Product